# set image height in aspect fill in auto layout in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uiimage, constraints

how to set the images in aspect fill when using the auto layout. When i design in storyboard it's perfectly fine but when setting the image, the height of image view goes very high. i want it to be a constant , i've also added the constant for that but it doesn't work. i'm using the latest Xcode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From Apple Document, `AspectFill` is not guaranteed to clip the content.

> The option to scale the content to fill the size of the view. Some
>   portion of the content may be clipped to fill the view’s bounds.

[image]

So you need to set `clipToBounds` property to True, or set it in Storyboard.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a million luiyezheng about this thing in the code. It really solved the thing for me. i can't up vote you right now sorry , i'm a new member

Answer (score 0):

set the imageView's `clipToBounds` property to true. In the storyboard this is the "Clip Subviews" checkbox.